# Why use `super` in a self.ransackable_attributes method? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ransack

What does `super` do in a `ransackable_attributes` method?

I'm looking at a Rails app with the below code in a model file.

```
private
def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
  super & %w(orientation classification form)
end
```

This is my first time using `ransack` and am not very familiar with `super`.

Does anyone mind sharing some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super` makes a call to the same method on the parent class, with the identical parameters as the current method call. In this case, it seems likely there is a default set of attributes. This would then perform an intersection on those default attributes and `%w(orientation classification form)`

For more info, [here is some example](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#authorization-whitelistingblacklisting) from the docs.